# Check each element of an array is hidden

Tags: ios

i want to know how to check each element of an array is hidden??
my array contain 20 buttons

```
btnsArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9,btn10,btn11,btn12,btn13,btn14,btn15,btn16,btn17,btn18,btn19,btn20, nil];
```

each button hides with a condition...

Actually i am trying to develop a memory match game. I have a timer of two min as well. if user finishes before the time what condition should i put that popup the alert that you win???
any suggestions ?

Comment: `if ([btnsArr[index] isHidden])`?

Comment: filter the array using a predicate "predicate to see if there is any button that is not hidden" ..if this filtered array has count more than 0 then not finished. otherwise if "== 0" then win.

Comment: You can remove buttons from dictionary after a match. After the timer completes, Check if array has any content. If all the matches are done, array will be empty else no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, if you want to know if all are hidden, you can iterate and break:

```
BOOL allHidden = YES;

for (UIButton *button in btnsArr) {
    if (!button.hidden) {
        allHidden = NO;
        break;
    }
}

NSLog(@"All hidden: %@", (allHidden ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
```

Comment: BOOL allHidden = YES;
    
    for (UIButton *button in btnsArr) {
        if (!button.hidden) {
            allHidden = NO;
          

            break;
        }
    }
    if (allHidden==YES) {
        
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"you win"                                                    message:@"Times Up !" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    }      this is working for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one

```
for(int i = 0; i < [btnsArr count] i++)
{

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[btnsArr objectAtIndex:i];
    if(btn.hidden)
    {
                //here btn is hidden ,
    }else
    {
                 //here btn is  not hidden
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<btnsArr.count;i++)
{
  UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[btnsArr objectAtIndex:i];
  if(btn.hidden)
  {
  }
  else
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumberate through the array to check if any instance of button is not hidden

```
__block BOOL buttonVisibile = NO;

[btnsArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    UIButton* btn = (UIButton*)obj;
            if(![btn isHidden]){
            //Do something
             buttonVisible = YES;
            }
}];

if(buttonVisible){
   //All of them are not hidden.
}
```